# Netbeans Maven Project dont detect new classes added or package added?

Tags: maven, netbeans

I, i have imported a Maven Project on Netbeans. I have add new package, and new classes to the projects, but Maven Project only detect default package.

Help?

Comment: Did you build your project already?

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed your new source files in the correct directory?

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Or have a look in the effective-pom, whether the path of your sources matches the configuration! [image]